# XML Validate Using Linq-to-XSD

Tags: .net, xsd, linq-to-xsd

I have generated class code using `linq-to-xsd` using multiple `XSD schemas`. I want to validate an `XML` using that class that is already created and not using every time the `xsd` files.

Thanks.